# Scraping Data Values from Website using BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I was trying to scrape latitude and longitude coordinate data from a website utilizing beautiful soup and requests. I am able to access the elements via span id, but cannot figure out how to pull off the white numerical value when looking at the websites html source code. All I need is the numerical value not element name.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://mycurrentlocation.net/"

# Send a GET request to the website and parse the HTML content
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Find the latitude and longitude elements using their CSS class names
lat_elem = soup.find("span", id="detail-latitude")
lng_elem = soup.find("span", id="detail-longitude")

# Print the latitude and longitude values
print("Latitude string:", lat_elem)
print("Longitude string:", lng_elem)

lat = soup.find("span", id="detail-latitude").text
lng = soup.find("span", id="detail-longitude").text

print("Latitude:", lat)
print("Longitude:", lng)
```

I would post images but stack overflow doesn't allow me since this is a new account.

I was expecting for the numerical values to be either .value, .text, or .attribute, but none of those appeared to work. I know how to, but don't want to use selenium since I plan to move this to Pythonista on an IOS device in the future. Thanks again!